# What is the connection between finite automata and logic (sequential calculus)?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, logic

> Languages recognized by finite automata are exactly those definable
> by sentences of the sequential calculus, and also exactly those
> definable by rational expressions (also called regular expressions)

*Howard Straubing, Pascal Weil. An introduction to finite automata and their connection to logic. Deepak D’Souza, Priti Shankar. Modern applications of automata theory, World Scientific, pp.3-43, 2012, IISc Research Monographs. hal-00541028v2*

Can you please explain, what is the connection between finite automata and sequential calculus (logic)?

Comment: sequential calculus = regular expressions ?

Comment: @nirshahar sequential calculus != regular expressions. I have updated the question.

Comment: The sequential calculus that is treated here is Büchi's calculus of monadic second order logic. Both automata and this logic define the regular languages, like is stated in the quote in your question. Please secify your question.